# Гусь на проволоке

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Здравствуйте. Интересно происхождение оборота "как гусь на проволоке".

Answer (score 2):

А где Вы слышали такое выражение? В какой ситуации? Я никогда такого выражения не встречала. Как с гуся вода. Гусь свинье не товарищ. Хорош гусь.Гусь лапчатый - вот , пожалуй, и все, что вспоминается из устойчивых оборотов.

Comment: В частности у Гиляровского встречалось. У Чехова и Куприна тоже, если не ошибаюсь. Похоже, это был армейский сленг.

Comment: А, вот цитата из "Моих скитаний" Гиляровского:
"А у кого неправильная боевая стойка, Ермилов из себя выходит: 
- Чего тебя скрючило? Живот, что ли, болит, сиволапый! Ты вольготно держись, как генерал в карете развались, а ты, как баба над подойником... Гусь на проволоке!"

Comment: эта цитата есть в интернете. Хорошо бы еще увидеть цитаты. А то и правду просто метафора получается.

Comment: Что такое "просто метафора"? 
Я уж не говорю о том, что она должна быть очевидно понятна собеседникам Ермилова.

Comment: метафора это и есть метафора. Образное выражение, содержащее скрытое сравнение. О Ермилове и говорится, ЧТО он любил образные выражения. Вряд ли можно назвать выражение оборотом, если оно  так редко встречается: его нет ни в одном словаре, нет в нац. корпусе.

Comment: Лорана, делаю попытку переспросить.
Вы употребили выражение  "прпосто метафора". Смысла его вы не пояснили. Более того, попытались тстрои ть на нёи какое-то опровержение.
Хотельось бы понять, какой смысл вкладываете в это понятие - и чему вдруг оно стало аргументом.  
Касательно того, оборот это или не оборот, я спорить не буду, ибо глупо спорить о терминах вообще, а в данном случае - особенно. Хоть горшком назови, вопрос был о смысле такого сравнения, а не об его "вумном" названии.  
ЗЫ Я никого не оскорблю, если что.

Comment: просто здесь обсуждалось не только происхождение, но и окказиональность или нет.

Comment: Я уже могу считать, что вы меня культурно послали?

Ну короче, не вижу оснований для какого-то переосмысливания версий только на основании того, что кто-то назвал это "просто метафорой". Тем более коглда втор формулировки не в состоянии пояснить, что он имел в виду.

Насчет окказионализма. Не похоже. Окказионализм должен быть интуитивно понтен окружающим. А мы вот гадаем... Да и контекст не тот, чтобы окказионализмами кидаться.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос где-то обсуждался несколько лет назад, найти, увы, не смог. Воспроизвожу результаты.
Выражение есть у Гиляровкого, по контексту не похоже, что окказионально.
Две версии происхождения. 
~1. В казачьих, если не ошибаюсь, войсках для тренировки штыкового удара подвешивали тушку гуся. Смысл тот, что пробить штыком болтающуюся цель не так просто в сравнении  с неподвижной - и именно такой удар считается правильным для боя. Позднее вместо реальной птицы стали использовать туго набитый соломой небольшой мешок, который тоже называли "гусем".
Косвенным подтверждением является использование выражения преимущественно в военном контексте. Некоторые сомненения насчет проволоки снимаются соображением о возможности использования названия "проволока" в отношении любой веревки. Хотя именно проволока подходила идаельно.   
~2. Отсылка к цирку (акробаты на проволоке). Сомнительно, насколько знаю, гусей никогда не использовали в подобных целях.

Comment: Первая версия вполне убедительна. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А  откуда  следует,  что  это  не  личное  творчество  этого  самого  Ермилова,  а  общеизвестное,  хоть  и  армейское, выражение.  По  смыслу  сближается  с  выражением  "корова  на  льду".

Comment: Не похоже, что оккаазионально, я писал. используется как вполне понятное.   
И потом оно не только у дяди Гиляя есть.

Comment: Я теперь узнал про Вашу слабость!!! Это слово "окказионально"

Comment: Точно, не  знал. Теперь буду.

Comment: -?!  
Слово как слово. Даже с обычной опечаткой.  

ЗЫ. Я еще умных словов знаю. 

*Мадмуазель Собак слыла культурной девушкой — в ее словаре было около ста восьмидесяти слов. При этом ей было известно одно такое слово, которое Эллочке даже не могло присниться. Это было богатое слово — гомосексуализм. Фима Собак, несомненно, была культурной девушкой.*

Comment: Участник В., Вы уверены, что на Вас никто не обидится?  )))

Comment: По-моему, это довольно добродушная шутка

Comment: >Участник В., Вы уверены, что на Вас никто не обидится? )))  

Здесь все возможно. Но я всё ещё рассчитываю, что на сей раз мне дадут знать это прежде чем делать оргвыводы.

Кстати, у вас там "В." русская или латинская?

Comment: Русская, но имеется в виду латинская. Ищем допустимые выражения методом проб и ошибок! ))) В этот раз прокатило.

Comment: Не  надо  делать  оргвыводы. Никто  и  не  обижается.  В  других  случаях  употребление  этого  выражения  тоже  связано  с  армейской  средой ?  У  казаков  не  было  штыка  на  вооружении. Но  это  не  столь  важно.  Проволока  же  действительно  вызывает  сомнения.

Comment: Цирковой  вариант  мне  больше  нравится. Именно  из-за  проволоки.